# I am having an issue with PageMenu

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

I am having that issue when I using PageMenu Framework and put all code for the PageMenu but its showing white space in my controller. Anybody have the solutions for that type of issue.let me know how can I remove it.

Blow I put complete code for PageMenu

[image]

```
import UIKit
import PageMenu

class TradingHistoryVC: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var pagerView: UIView!

var controllerArray : [UIViewController] = []
var pageMenu : CAPSPageMenu?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


     navigationController?.navigationBar.topItem?.title = ""
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    pager()
}

func pager()
{
    let buy = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "TradingSuccessfullyVCSID") as! TradingSuccessfullyVC
    buy.parentNavigationController = navigationController!
    buy.title = "Trading Successfully"
    controllerArray.append(buy)

    let sell = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "GlobalTradingVCSID") as! GlobalTradingVC
    sell.parentNavigationController = navigationController!
    sell.title = "Global Trading"
    controllerArray.append(sell)



    // Customize menu (Optional)
    let parameters: [CAPSPageMenuOption] = [
        .scrollMenuBackgroundColor(UIColor(red: 72/255.0, green: 175/255.0, blue: 230/255.0, alpha: 1.0)),
        .viewBackgroundColor(UIColor(red: 255.0/255.0, green: 255.0/255.0, blue: 255.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)),

        .selectionIndicatorColor(UIColor(red: 255/255, green: 255/255, blue: 255/255, alpha: 1.0)),
        .addBottomMenuHairline(false),
        .menuItemFont(UIFont(name: "Times New Roman", size: 16)!),
        .menuItemWidth((self.pagerView.frame.width-30)/2),
        .menuHeight(50.0),
        .enableHorizontalBounce(true),
        .menuItemWidthBasedOnTitleTextWidth(false),
        .selectedMenuItemLabelColor(UIColor.white),

        .unselectedMenuItemLabelColor(UIColor.white),
        .menuItemSeparatorWidth(4.5),
        .useMenuLikeSegmentedControl(false),
        .menuItemSeparatorRoundEdges(true),
        .selectionIndicatorHeight(2.0),
        .menuItemSeparatorPercentageHeight(0.0),
        ]

    // Initialize scroll menu
    pageMenu = CAPSPageMenu(viewControllers: controllerArray, frame: CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: self.pagerView.frame.width, height: self.pagerView.frame.height), pageMenuOptions: parameters)

    self.pagerView.addSubview(pageMenu!.view)

    // End Pagemenu
}


@IBAction func btnMenuAction(_ sender: Any) {
    toggleSideMenuView()
}
}
```

If anyone have its solutions plz. Please Help to solve it.

Comment: Pagemenu have so many issues like that unfortunately their support are very less better you go for alternatives  https://github.com/GaneshManickam/PageMenuKitSwift  This is an one of the alternative library those functionalities similar to PageMenu

Comment: You are not calling `super` in your `viewController` which may be caused this behavior. Try  `override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
     super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    pager()
}`

Comment: @deoKasuhal can you explain me? what you want to say?

Comment: @deoKasuhal Its has no effect. I already put it but it is showing white space with it.

Comment: can you do a test after changing the background color in each controller like `buy.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.red` and `buy.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.gray` see if the space is showing becase of code is in `TradingHistoryVC` or its `childViewControllers`.